# Stop all files upload if an error occurs - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, upload

I created some code that allows the user to upload in a MySQL database some images.
Here are my two problems:

1. When an error occurrs, e.g. because a file is not an image, the file
   in question is not loaded, but the other files do.
    Contrariwise I
   want that, when even just an error occurs, **no files** are uploaded.
   *Example*: If I upload 3 files, and 1 of them is not an image:

   - My output now, which I don't want:
     `File 1 uploaded
     File 2 uploaded
     Just JPG and PNG images are allowed // file 3 not uploaded`
   - What i expect to have:
     `No files uploaded // Even if a single file is not good, nobody gets uploaded`
2. If I upload *n* files, *n* messages will be printed. For example, if I upload 3 files, this will be the output:
   `File 1.png upload correctly
   File 2.png upload correctly
   File 3.png upload correctly`

   But what I hope to have is only one sentence, like `3 files uploaded`.

Here is my code:

```
$timestamp = time();
$total = count($_FILES[ 'upload' ][ 'name' ]);
                if ($total==0) {
                    echo "Please upload at least one file";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                } else {
                    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
                        if ($tmpFilePath != '') {
                            $newFilePath = "./uploadFiles/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
                            $completeFileName = basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"][$i]);
                            $target_file = "uploads/$completeFileName"; $uploadOk = 1;
                            $estensione = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                            $Name = basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"][$i]);
                            if($extension != 'jpg' && $extension != 'png') {
                                echo "Only JPG and PNG files are allowed";
                                $uploadOk = 0;
                            } else {
                                $fileName = str_replace(".$extension", '', $completeFileName);
                                $string = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 15);
                                $id = rand(1, 100000);
                                $finalFileName = 'uploads/'.$string.$id.'.'.$estensione;
                                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"][$i], $finalFileName)) {
                                    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'example', '', 'my_example');
                                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO uploads (timestamp, file) VALUES ('$timestamp', '$finalFileName')");
                                      echo "<h2>The file <i>$fileName</i> has been uploaded.</h2>";
                                } else echo "Error";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I hope that my explanation is clear.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! I thought that it is not possibile to make an SQL injection with an image input...

Comment: SQL injection is not about the input, it is about your code. You have a bug in the code and it doesn't matter where the input comes from. You must parameterize your queries.

Comment: What bug are you referring to, and what do you mean with "parameterize your queries"? (sorry, but I'm new with PHP)

Comment: This `$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO uploads (timestamp, file) VALUES ('$timestamp', '$finalFileName')");` Please read a good tutorial to learn how to fix it: https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection

Comment: In this way, however, I should change my whole code, and I don't have the skills

Comment: @Dharman would you be so kind to help me do develope this solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
/*
 * CREATE TABLE `uploads` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
 */

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'devel', 'devel', 'upload_db');

$timestamp = time();
$success_images = [];
$total = count($_FILES[ 'upload' ][ 'name' ]);
if ($total == 0) {
    echo "Please upload at least one file";
    $uploadOk = 0;
} else {

    $uploadOk = 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES[ "upload" ][ "tmp_name" ][ $i ];
        if ($tmpFilePath != '') {
            $newFilePath = "./uploadFiles/" . $_FILES[ 'upload' ][ 'name' ][ $i ];
            $Name = basename($_FILES[ "upload" ][ "name" ][ $i ]);
            $parts = pathinfo($Name);
            $extension = strtolower($parts[ 'extension' ]);
            if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'png') {

                // there may be $newFilePath I think
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[ "upload" ][ "tmp_name" ][ $i ], $newFilePath)) {

                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO uploads (timestamp, file) VALUES ('$timestamp', '$Name')");
                    $id = $mysqli->insert_id;
                    $success_images[ $id ] = $newFilePath;
                    $uploadOk = 1;

                } else {

                    echo "Error";
                    $uploadOk = 0;

                    break; // break loop !!!
                }
            } else {

                echo "Just JPG and PNG files are allowed";
                $uploadOk = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($uploadOk === 0) {

        foreach ($success_images as $id => $filename) {
            // `id` - primary key of table uploads?
            $mysqli->query(sprintf('DELETE FROM uploads WHERE `id`=%d', $id));
            if (file_exists($filename)) {
                unlink($filename);
            }
        }
    } else {

        foreach ($success_images as $id => $filename) {

            echo "<h2>The file <i>$filename</i> has been uploaded.</h2>";

        }

    }
}

?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" multiple name="upload[]"/>
    <input type="submit" value="do_upload"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please post some code? I do not really understand what you mean

Comment: There is more practices how work with uploaded files: use own filenames (example: id from file table's record), actual filename store in table. File with extension .jpg or .png doesn't mean, that is really images jpg resp. png. Try function getimagesize for simple check valid image.

Comment: Mhh, it is not working... why is `$success_images[ $id ] = $newFilePath;`?

Comment: If I execute your code the images are not inserted in the database

Comment: `$newFilePath` looks like path in file system to store image.

Comment: "images are not inserted" records or values?

Comment: I think values (**no new items** are created in the database)

Comment: Missing code after loop start: `$tmpFilePath = $_FILES[ "upload" ][ "tmp_name" ][ $i ];`

Comment: Yes, I know, when I cleaned the code I made an error. I edit my post, try to watch it again

Comment: I add test code (with extension - i see your changes), current updated source work (I test in `php7/mysqli/mysql 5.7`)

Comment: Fantastic, I retried and your code works! There is just a problem: even if the files for an error are not uploaded, it appears the text _"The file_ myImg _has been uploaded"_

Comment: Yes, we must move output after upload loop - https://pastebin.com/raw/CweA5c0z - I update it, now.

Comment: But is also possible to not generate a text for every file, but create just one written like "Upload succesful" or "Upload failed" (for all the files)? PS: THANKS for the help

Comment: Yes, you may use variable `$uploadOk` and show text by this status.